# dynamically add rows and then insert date into database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i want to add rows using loop and then want user to fill the rows then i want these rows' data (tds contain textboxes and selection lists)to be saved into database? i need to know how is it possible?  jquery and php will be preferred.

DatA not datE.

Comment: Are you talking about datA or about inserting a datE. Pleas be more clear.

Comment: Please specify your question further. What did you try? Which code did not work? It's impossible to answer the question like this without any detail. Yes, it is possible. How depends on your needs.

Comment: @Joris Meys +1, I totally agree, I'm quite confused right now ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way to do this is to create a php file which will take arguments from jquery and execute it.
 while assigning each element of form a unique id and counting total rows will give us a chance to use loop and we can send each row elements' data using  loop. php file will get the arguments and execute it .the ajax request will be send count-row times.

Answer (score 0):

run this command in loop. rows automatically added in your table

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name(feild1, feild2) VALUES ('value1', 'value2')");